# Output of sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier includes NaN values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I am using [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) to analyze data and I was puzzled to see NaN values in the prediction without any NaN in the training set or in testing set.

```
print preds_y[preds_y.isnull().any(axis=1)].shape
print train_y[train_y.isnull().any(axis=1)].shape
print train_features[train_features.isnull().any(axis=1)].shape
print test_features[train_features.isnull().any(axis=1)].shape

> (4830, 1)
> (0, 1)
> (0, 22)
> (0, 22)
```

These NaN values are causing the call to [sklearn.metrics.classification_report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) to fail with the following error:

```
> ValueError: Mix of label input types (string and number)
```

Right now I'm mostly interested in understanding why the random forest is spitting out NaNs. As soon as I figure that out, I can filter the results accordingly and see how well the method is performing.

Thanks in advance for your input.

(I'm sorry if this has been asked before. I searched for it but all the results I found concerned NaNs in the training data, which is not my issue at all.)

**EDIT 1:** Just to be clear, there are many valid predictions in the output:

```
print preds_y[~preds_y.isnull().any(axis=1)].shape
print train_y[~train_y.isnull().any(axis=1)].shape

> (11760, 1)
> (39749, 1)
```

**EDIT 2:**

As I wrote in a comment below, the original data has numeric and categorical columns. All the categorical columns are converted to numeric using pandas.get_dummies() before calling fit(). I convert the results back to a pandas.DataFrame and reconstruct the original categorical columns for readability. The two pandas.Series -- predicted and actual values -- I am feeding classification_report() have only one type (category).

It seems that the NaNs in the predictions arise if the random forest predicts 0 for every dummy binary column corresponding to the original categorical column. I was not expecting this to happen so often -- it seems that 30% of my entries go unclassified -- but I'm not sure there is anything further to add on this issue.

Comment: What does your data look like? Does the target class have mixed types?

Comment: The original data has numeric and categorical columns. All the categorical columns are converted to numeric using pandas.get_dummies() before calling fit(). I convert the results back to a pandas.DataFrame and reconstruct the original categorical columns for readability. The two pandas.Series -- predicted and actual values -- I am feeding classification_report() have only one type (category).

Answer (score -1):

You can first remove all `NaN` by replacing them as zeros. 
See [this link](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_missing_data/).

Maybe use `df.fillna(0)`, then you should be fine I suppose.